# Pivot table select in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a pivot table for my table `users` and `courses`.

A user can have many courses and a course can have many courses. So,

In `Course.php`

```
 public function user(){
       return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
```

and in `User.php`

```
public function courses(){
    return $this->hasMany('Course');
}
```

When I tried to call the following query, an error appears.

```
$user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
$courses = $user->courses->get();
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'courses.user_id unknown in where clause (SQL: select * from `` Where courses` courses`.`user_id` = 3)
```

What might be the problem? Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **return** the relationship. Also you need to use `belongsToMany()` for many-to-many relations.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

and

```
public function courses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Course');
}
```

[⇒ Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

Comment: I'm getting an error still then

`SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'courses.user_id unknown in where clause (SQL: select * from `` Where courses` courses`.`user_id` = 3)`

Comment: Can you please reformat the error message or add it to your question? It's kind of hard to read like that.

Comment: And the foreign key referencing user.id is called `user_id`?

Comment: dd($users) Returns array (size=3) and other details.

Comment: Okay. and fetching all courses? (I'm really irritated by the `select * from ''` and have the feeling that's the problem)

Comment: Yes, it is also returning non empty array

Comment: Ouhh well. Of course you need to use `belongsToMany()` and not `hasMany()`!!

Comment: So both course and user has to be `belongsToMany()` ?

Comment: Yes. Also see the [documentation on this topic](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

Comment: Alright. This worked. You might want to edit the answer and submit it again so that I can mark it as completed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$user = User::with('courses')->where('id', Auth::id())->first();` wich would do your code in a single line.

Then you could use `$user->courses` as an array to access the cources.

Note that `Auth::id()` is an equivalent to `Auth::user()->id`.

EDIT : You should use the following function for the courses :

```
public function user()
{
   return ($this->belongsToMany('User'));
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE [42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'learningnew.user_user' does not exist (SQL: select * `users`,` `as user_user`.`user_id` pivot_user_id` from` users` inner. `` we join user_user` users`.`id` = `` Where user_user`.`user_id` user_user`.`user_id` in (3))

Comment: You have to use the function I posted in your Course class and not change the function in your User class. Sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: I did that. This error occurred: 

SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'courses.user_id unknown in where clause (SQL: select * from `` Where courses` courses`.`user_id` in (3))